# Why drawing a texture using Opengl ( using rust ) is showing border colour

Tags: opengl, rust, 2d, textures, texture2d

I am drawing this texture using opengl and rust. But for some reason the image has border around it when I draw away from the top left. I think there is something wrong with matrix / viewport. Not entirely sure.

[image: Smiley Face]

```
let width = 1280; // Window is initialised to these values. Hard coded for context.
let height = 720;

unsafe { 
    gl::Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

let orth = cgmath::ortho::<f32>(0.0, width as f32, height as f32, 0.0, -1.00, 100.0)

unsafe { 
    gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl::CLAMP_TO_BORDER as i32);
    gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl::CLAMP_TO_BORDER as i32);
    gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);
    gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);

    let border_colour = [0.9, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0];
    gl::TexParameterfv(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, border_colour.as_ptr());
        
    gl::TexImage2D(
        gl::TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        gl::RGBA as i32,
        img.width as i32,
        img.height as i32,
        0,
        gl::RGBA,
        gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        data.as_ptr() as *const c_void,
    );

    gl::GenerateMipmap(gl::TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Before Drawing the texture, I clear the display

```
pub fn clear_frame_buffer() {
    unsafe {
        gl::Clear(gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl::DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl::ClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}
```

Drawing the texture:

```
pub fn draw_quad(tex: &Texture2D, program : &Program, mesh : &Mesh, projection : &Matrix4<f32>, position : Vector3<f32>) { 

    program.bind();
    mesh.vao.bind();
    tex.bind();

    if let Some(location) = program.get_uniform_location("view") { 
        let camera_transform = Matrix4::<f32>::identity() * Matrix4::from_scale(1.0);
        program.set_matrix(location, &[camera_transform]);
    }

    if let Some(location) = program.get_uniform_location("projection") { 
        program.set_matrix(location, &[*projection]);
    }

    if let Some(location) = program.get_uniform_location("model") { 
        let model = {
            let translate = Matrix4::<f32>::from_translation(position);
            let (w, h) = tex.get_dimensions();
            let scale = Matrix4::<f32>::from_nonuniform_scale(w as f32, h as f32, 1.0);
            translate * scale
        };
        program.set_matrix(location, &[model]);
    }

    let count = mesh.count as i32;

    unsafe { 
        gl::DrawArrays(gl::TRIANGLES, 0, count);
    }
}
```

Then I move the texture
[image: Moved Smiley Face]

I know the pink is coming from my color text param. But I shouldn't be able to see it? I should be only drawing the image and not the border.

```
let quad_vertices: [f32; 30] = [
    // Positions        // Texcoords
    1.0, -1.0, 0.0,     1.0, 0.0, 
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,    0.0, 0.0, 
    -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,     0.0, 1.0, 

    1.0, 1.0, 0.0,      1.0, 1.0, 
    1.0, -1.0, 0.0,     1.0, 0.0, 
    -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,     0.0, 1.0,
];
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex; 
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texcoords; 

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = texcoords;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D image;

void main()
{    
    color = texture(image, TexCoords);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your shader code and how you pass your vertices?

Comment: Where do you clear the display?

Comment: I added the framebuffer clear. So order of execution is. Swap buffers, clear display, draw textures.